# pserve dies when started from Jenkins job

Tags: python, jenkins, pyramid

I have an UAT job that runs tests in Pyramid app and then starts `pserve` to create live instance for UAT testing. However, when I start `pserve` from Jenkins job, it dies for no apparent reason:

```
cd "$WORKSPACE"
. ve/bin/activate 
pserve development.ini start --pid-file=/tmp/uat.pid --log-file="$WORKSPACE"/uat.log  --daemon --reload
```

The strange thing is that if I do the same thing from commandline and then exit SSH session, `pserve` lives on.

How's that possible?

Comment: Which version of Pyramid? Are there any relevant messages in your logfile `"$WORKSPACE"/uat.log`?